# Probability distribution of iid variables

Tags: probability

Three i.i.d. random variables have a uniform distribution $0$ to $2$. What is the probability that the median is $> 1.5$?

Is the answer, $0.25^3 = 0.015625$?

Comment: No.  That's the probability that all three are greater than $1.5$...but there are triples, like $(1.75, 1.9, 1.45)$ in which the median is $>1.5$ but not all the terms are.

Comment: I got it..so only 2 variables need to be > 1.5. So the probability is 0.0625 right?

Comment: No...you have two cases.  First case (which you have done) is that all three are $>1.5$.  Second case is that exactly two of them are $>1.5$.  What is the probability that, say, the first and second are $>1.5$ but the third is $<1.5$?

Comment: the 3rd variable is irrelevant because as long as 2 are > 1.5. in which case median is > 1.5

Comment: It is not irrelevant, since the two cases must be handled separately. There are, that is to say, several ways in which at least two out of three can be big. If $X$ denotes a number $>1.5$ and $Y$ a number $<1.5$ then you have to consider the triples $XXX, XXY, XYX, YXX$.

Comment: 1) 2 variables are > 1.5 and third variable is also > 1.5 = probability is 0.25*.25*.25
2) 2 variables are > 1.5 and third variable is also <= 1.5 = probability is 0.25*.25*.75

Adding Case 1 and 2 gives = 0.0625*(0.25+0.75) = 0.0625

Comment: Ok, but you have three of the type two cases.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean...makes sense.

Comment: When you have a final number you should test it.  this is very easy to simulate on a spread sheet, say.

Comment: thank you so much for your insights..lulu..